# How can i do multi domain config NGINX with tomcat?

Tags: nginx, tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat9

I have one Cloud Server and 2 domain. 
I have one success but second domain not working.
working conf;

```
server {
  listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
  server_name www.fromthepast.org fromthepast.org;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/fromthepast-access.log main;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/fromthepast-error.log;

  location / {

        proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
  }
}
```

You can see enter the website fromthepast.org its working correct.

wrong conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
  server_name www.suyla.org suyla.org;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/suylaaccess.log main;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/suyla-error.log;

  location / {

        proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/denizhan;
  }
}
```

actually its working but not correct. 
 you can see enter suyla.org > redirect http://suyla.org:8080/denizhan  
i dont want :8080 port, just suyla.org or suyla.org/denizhan

How can i do multi domain config NGINX with tomcat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it. example; 
/etc/nginx/conf.d

```
server {
  listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
  server_name www.suyla.org suyla.org;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/suyla-access.log main;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/suyla-error.log;
  location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/;
  }
}
```

and redirejct 8082 
 
one more config > ../tomcat/conf/server.xml

```
<Service name="denizhan">
   <Connector port="8082" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8444" />
   <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Context path="" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/denizhan" reloadable="false" useHttpOnly="true">
                        <Manager pathname=""/>
                </Context>

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_accessss_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
   </Engine>
</Service>
```

if i want one more domain and app, i will redirect 8083, thankx for all

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your config to something like that:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.suyla.org suyla.org;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/suylaaccess.log main;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/suyla-error.log;

  location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/denizhan;
  }
}
```

Comment: [errorimage](http://prntscr.com/swqd6n) its not redirect but not working

Comment: Probably need to remove `denizhan` from proxy_pass? Like `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;` If you want to add `/denizhan` as `base url` instead of `/`, then it should also be configured at tomcat application.

Comment: no no, i have one tomcat tow domain
fromthepast.org   > localhost:8080/  
suyla.org              > localhost:8080/denizhan

Comment: Ok if you have only one tomcat application, then try to change location to: `location /denizhan/ { ` and set proxy_pass to: `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;`

Comment: [suyla.org] http://prntscr.com/swqvww
i did >> server {
  listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
  server_name www.suyla.org suyla.org;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/suyla-access.log main;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/suyla-error.log;
  location /denizhan/ {
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/

  }
}

Comment: Please note, you need to put the correct URL at you browser, `http://suyla.org/denizhan`

Comment: yes i did but 2 wrong, first its not correct app, and second http://prntscr.com/swr8kv

Comment: i fixed, thanx for help